# Filter issue in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

A filled datagridview control with a filter procedure with numbers as string. All word fine except do not show value = 100%

Column values: 62%, 71%, 75%, 80%, 88%, 92%, 100%

Code:

```
dv = New DataView(dTable, String.Format("L15 >= '{0}%'", TextBox1.Text), "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

EX. If write 80 in TextBox show 80%, 88%, 92% but not 100%

Try with many convinations but nothing, What I missing?

Regards.

Comment: `filter procedure with numbers as string`  Avoid that.  If it's a number, don't make it into a string.  You can always *format* numbers for display.

Comment: Datagrid import the values from a text file. I try to convert with Cint but give a error

Comment: You should solve that issue first.  Prefer `int.TryParse` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't populated the grid with `Strings`. A `DataGridView` is perfectly capable of storing non-text values and formatting them as text.  What you should be doing is storing numbers in the `DataTable`, binding it to a `BindingSource` and binding that to the grid.  You can set the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property of the grid column to format the numbers as percentages.  If you store `Double` or `Decimal` values like 0.62 then "p0" would be the format specifier for percentages. You can then set the `Filter` of the `BindingSource` to filter in-place.